# Identificação de versão em projetos Web

Tags: java, deploy, jenkins

Trabalho com WebServices em vários servidores glassfish, e atualmente a identificação da versão é feita no próprio arquivo .war, exemplo:

> teste-1.0.war

Gostaria de saber se essa é maneira certa, ou então, qual seria a maneira certa (web.xml e pom.xml) para identificar um projeto no servidor glassfish?

A dúvida surgiu pois estou utilizando o jenkins para automatizar meu deploy e na implantação ele remove a versão do nome do arquivo .war ficando assim:

> teste.war

Comment: Desculpe, mas não entendi muito bem a sua dúvida. Você quer diferenciar o projeto em versões para poder subir mais de uma versão ao mesmo tempo ou apenas para identificá-lo mesmo? Nos projetos em que trabalhei inferimos a versão no `pom.xml` através da tag `<version>`. O nome do `war` alteramos na tag `<finalName>` dentro de `<build>`, mas não colocamos a versão.

Comment: Para identificação mesmo. 
Já coloco a versão na tag <version> no pom.xml, mas a dúvida é como saber a versão via glassfish, pois lá não tenho acesso ao pom.xml. 
Tenho vários servidores, em cada servidor uma versão do webservice. Como identificar qual a versão do webservice que está em um servidor específico, utilizando o painel de administrador do glassfish?